# How to set the page for controller actions?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Now I want to set the `currentpage` by controller, then I can use it location to page data. I don't know how to pass this parameter:

```
if ($request->id != null) {
    $total=Comment::where('source_id',$request->source_id)->where('id','<',$request->id)->count();

    $place=$commentCount - $total;

    $currentPage=ceil($place/$count);
```

Comment: your requirement is not clear. Can you please explain more? Do you want to get current page in Controller?

Comment: @mithi want to set the current page by controller

Comment: you mean a redirect? https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#redirects